# asp.net core mvc add item to exiting model in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, asp.net-core, view

ASP.NET Core 2 MVC web app.

I have a page that inherit from a model and shows data that has to be modified. That model has a List<> that is render using a foreach

Here is my model

```
public class ParticipantModel
    {
        public List<ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel>? ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel { get; set; }
    }

public class ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel
{
      public string? FieldName { get; set; }
     public string? FieldValue { get; set; }
}
```

In the Page I have this

```
 @foreach (var participantSpecifiFields in Model.ParticipantModel)
        {
            <div style="float:left; width:80%;">
                <div class="col-2" style="float:left;">
                    <span style="font-weight:bold;">@participantSpecifiFields.FieldName</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2" style="float:left;">
                    <span>@participantSpecifiFields.FieldValue</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

I need to Submit the form and I was thinking to use

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Update", "Client")" id="formUpdate" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

The problem I have is that, apart from updated existing items, I can add a new one.

I tried with

```
<div class="col">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel![X].FieldName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel![X].FieldValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
```

Where X is the last index +1. But does not work.

If there a way to add Items to an existing Model? and send it to Controller when I submit?

Thanks

Comment: You can't have an "EditorFor" for something that doesn't exist.  You either need to update the model on the controller side (adding one), or create the input fields more manually with the index... (ex: <input name="ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel[x]...")  In general when you're tying the form fields to a model's list, you'd iterate with a standard for loop and use Model.ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel[for-loop-index]... in your htmlHelpers.  You'd then update the model to add a blank item via the controller if an "add item" button is clicked.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a view model here...  you should probably include that in your question.  (it couldn't hurt to add the whole controller & cshtml as people can give a more specific answer...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mr pcalkins said, you can use `EditorFor(xxx)` for something doesn't exist, So here, I think you can set a button, When user click the button, use JavaScript to generate an `input` element for user to input the value of `FieldName` and `FieldValue`. Here is a simple demo. Hope it can give you some help.

**Controller**

```
      //For testing, I just hard code here.
        ParticipantModel model = new ParticipantModel()
        {
            ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel = new List<ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel>()
            {
                new ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel()
                {
                    FieldName ="AAA",
                    FieldValue = "aaaaa"
                },
                new ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel()
                {
                    FieldName ="BBB",
                    FieldValue = "bbbbb"
                },
                new ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel()
                {
                    FieldName ="CCC",
                    FieldValue = "ccccc"
                },
                new ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel()
                {
                    FieldName ="DDD",
                    FieldValue = "ddddd"
                }
            }
        };


        public IActionResult Hello()
        {
            return View(model);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model ParticipantModel

<form method="post">
    <div data="@Model.ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel.Count()" id="count"></div>
    @for (var i = 0;i<Model.ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel.Count();i++)
    {
        <div style="float:left; width:80%;">
            <div class="col-2" style="float:left;">
                <span style="font-weight:bold;">@Model.ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel[i].FieldName</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel[@i].FieldName" value="@Model.ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel[i].FieldName" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-2" style="float:left;">
                <span>@Model.ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel[i].FieldValue</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel[@i].FieldValue" value="@Model.ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel[i].FieldValue" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <br />
    <div id="new-fields-container"></div>
    <br />
    <button id="add-field" type="button">Add Field</button>
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $('#add-field').click(function () {

            var newIndex = document.getElementById("count").getAttribute('data')
            var newHtml = '<div class="col">' +
                '<input type="text" name="ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel[' + newIndex + '].FieldName" class="form-control" />' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="col">' +
                '<input type="text" name="ParticipantSpecificFieldsModel[' + newIndex + '].FieldValue" class="form-control" />' +
                '</div>';
            $('#new-fields-container').append(newHtml);
            
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Demo**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Diego, Can this answer solved your issue?